# Add OpenMP to program to calculate the determinant of an n x n matrix n x n

Tags: c++, multithreading, matrix, openmp

Here is code to find determinant of matrix n x n.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int determinant(int *matrix[], int size);
void ijMinor(int *matrix[], int *minorMatrix[], int size, int row, int column);

int main()
{
    int size;
    cout << "What is the size of the matrix for which you want to find the determinant?:\t";
    cin >> size;

    int **matrix;
    matrix = new int*[size];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
        matrix[i] = new int[size];

    cout << "\nEnter the values of the matrix seperated by spaces:\n\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            cin >> matrix[i][j];

    cout << "\nThe determinant of the matrix is:\t" << determinant(matrix, size) << endl;

    return 0;
}

int determinant(int *matrix[], int size){
    if(size==1)return matrix[0][0];
    else{
        int result=0, sign=-1;
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){

            int **minorMatrix;
            minorMatrix = new int*[size-1];
            for (int k = 0 ; k < size-1 ; k++)
                minorMatrix[k] = new int[size-1];

            ijMinor(matrix, minorMatrix, size, 0, j);

            sign*=-1;
            result+=sign*matrix[0][j]*determinant(minorMatrix, size-1);
            for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++){
                delete minorMatrix[i];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}

void ijMinor(int *matrix[], int *minorMatrix[], int size, int row, int column){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            if(i < row){
                if(j < column)minorMatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
                else if(j == column)continue;
                else minorMatrix[i][j-1] = matrix[i][j];
            }
            else if(i == row)continue;
            else{
                if(j < column)minorMatrix[i-1][j] = matrix[i][j];
                else if(j == column)continue;
                else minorMatrix[i-1][j-1] = matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After adding OpenMP pragmas, I've changed the determinant function and now it looks like this:

```
int determinant(int *matrix[], int size){
    if(size==1)return matrix[0][0];
    else{
        int result=0, sign=-1;
        #pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(size,matrix,sign) private(j,k)  reduction(+ : result)

        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){

            int **minorMatrix;

            minorMatrix = new int*[size-1];

            for (int k = 0 ; k < size-1 ; k++)
                minorMatrix[k] = new int[size-1];

            ijMinor(matrix, minorMatrix, size, 0, j);

            sign*=-1;
            result+=sign*matrix[0][j]*determinant(minorMatrix, size-1);
            for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++){
                delete minorMatrix[i];
            }
        }

        return result;    
        delete [] matrix;
    }
}
```

My problem is that the result is every time different. Sometimes it gives correct value, but most often it is wrong. I think it's because of the `sign` variable. I am following the formula:

[image: Formula]

As you can see, in every iteration of my for loop there should be different `sign` but when I use OpenMP, something is wrong. How can I make this program to run with OpenMP?

Finally, my second issue is that using OpenMP does not make the program run quicker than without OpenMP. I also tried to make a 100,000 x 100,000 matrix, but my program reports an error about allocating memory. How can I run this program with very large matrices?

Comment: *I tried to make matrix 100 000 x 100 000 and gives error with allocate memory* Can you allocate a matrix that large without OpenMP ?  If not, where do you imagine that OpenMP will get the memory from ?

Comment: I know that OpenMP will not get memory for this. I'm looking for another solution. This Topic has 2 problems. First with working OpenMP with this program. Second with anything I can do to calculate this big matrix. If there is nothing I can do with so large matrix than I will check OpenMP with smaller matrix.

Comment: Instead of `sign*=-1;` use should have `sign = (j % 2) ? -1 : 1;` or something of that kind. Also, `sign` should be `private`. In your current version different threads interfere with one another by constantly flipping the sign.

Comment: Now results are good all the time but there is problem with OpenMP. Without OpenMP it takes for matrix 10 x 10 about 1.3s. With OpenMP matrix 10 x 10 takes about 70s to calculate result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issues as I see it are as follows:

1) As noted by Hristo, your threads are stomping over each other's data with respect to the `sign` variable. It should be private to each thread so that they have full read/write access to it without having to worry about race conditions. Then, you simply need an algorithm to compute whether `sign` is plus or minus 1 depending on the iteration `j` *independently* from the other iterations. With a little thinking, you'll see that Hristo's suggestion is correct: `sign = (j % 2) ? -1 : 1;` should do the trick.

2) Your `determinant()` function is recursive. As is, that means that every iteration of the loop, after forming your minors, you then call your function again on that minor. Therefore, a single thread is going to be performing its iteration, enter the recursive function, *and then try to split itself up into `nthreads` more threads.* You can see now how you are oversubscribing your system by launching many more threads than you physically have cores. Two easy solutions:

- Call your original serial function from within the `omp parallel` code. This is the fastest way to do it because this would avoid any OpenMP-startup overhead.
- Turn off nested parallelism by calling `omp_set_nested(0);` before your first call to `determinant()`.
- Add an if clause to your parallel for directive: `if(omp_in_parallel())`

3) Your memory issues are because every iteration of your recursion, you are allocating more memory. If you fix problem #2, then you should be using comparable amounts of memory in the serial case as the parallel case. That being said, it would be much better to allocate all the memory you want before entering your algorithm. Allocating large chunks of memory (and then freeing it!), especially in parallel, is a terrible bottleneck in your code.

Compute the amount of memory you would need (on paper) before entering the first loop and allocate it all at once. I would also strongly suggest you consider allocating your memory contiguously (aka in 1D) to take better advantage of caching as well. Remember that each thread should have its own separate area to work with. Then, change your function to:

`int determinant(int *matrix, int *startOfMyWorkspace, int size)`.

Instead of allocating a new `(size-1)x(size-1)` matrix inside of your loop, you would simply utilize the next `(size-1)*(size-1)` integers of your workspace, update what `startOfMyWorkspace` would be for the next recursive call, and continue along.